# B2B Option Disabled Apple Connect

Tags: ios, swift

does anyone know why the b2b option is disabled?

Apple tells me that my app must be B2B to be able to release it, however I have not been able to select the B2B option, even using a new compilation of the app, and I'm not sure what I need to be able to make the option come out enabled.

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to have a little bit more context. What are you trying to accomplish? How? etc...

Comment: ok thanks, i can add more information

Comment: Have you previously released a version of this app to the App Store?

Comment: It has never been released in the app store

Comment: Do you have a signed  paid applications agreement with Apple under "Agreements tax and banking"?

Comment: I think not, how do you get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create the paid application contract.

[image]

[image]